# How can I convert a date format of type "Fri Jun 30 '17, 11:15:56 am" to "mm/dd/yyyy" format in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I have a need to convert dates of format `Fri Jun 30 '17, 11:15:56 am` to `mm/dd/yyyy` format using a VBA. I tried `format()` function but it didn't work.

Comment: Does excel detects it as a date inside the Cell? if it does try: =TEXT(A2, "mm/dd/yyyy") Edit: Additionally you may need to convert it to NUMERICVALUE then back to Date format in the cell, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the exact code you tried. Also include if the cells include a *real date* format or if this is saved as text only. • Note that *"didn't work"* is actually no error description, and completely meaningless. • It is highly recommendet never to use `format()` unless it is for displaying purpose only (eg a message box). If the date is within a cell use `Range.NumberFormat` to format the date.

Comment: @RicardoA my code crawls some log files and picks the last log date from the file. Since, the date format is different in some log files I wish to convert them to mm/dd/yyyy format before writing them to excel cells.

Answer (score 2):

If `format()` doesn't work, then (as you haven't told us otherwise) we have to assume that the cell contains that date as text, not as a date.

In which case, allow me to offer one ***of many*** methods of converting this to mm/dd/yyyy:

```
Format(DateValue(Replace(Mid(Split(Range("A1").Value, ", ")(0), 4, 20), "'", "")), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

As @Peh mentions though, this is not the best way to deal with  a date. It is better to hold the date as a *Date* - and if you're writing to a cell, to write that *Date* to the cell *as a Date*. This makes manipulation of the date much easier and you just apply formatting to the cell to get the desired look.

---

To get the *Date*, you could use:

```
DateValue(Replace(Mid(Split(Range("A1").Value, ", ")(0), 4, 20), "'", ""))
```

---

Explanation:

`Split(Range("A1").Value, ", ")(0)`

This creates an array that contains the string split in two, the first part `(0)` contains the left element, the second part `(1)` contains the right element.

So `Fri Jun 30 '17, 11:15:56 am` becomes `Fri Jun 30 '17`

We then take a portion of the left hand part above:

`Mid(<left hand part>, 4, 20)`

from character 4, for (up to) 20 characters.

So `Fri Jun 30 '17` becomes `Jun 30 '17`

We then remove the `'` using a `Replace(text , "'", "")` function.

So `Jun 30 '17` becomes `Jun 30 17`

The `DateValue` function converts strings that contain dates into an actual date value. `Jun 30 17` is recognisable to Excel as a date and given that the month element is obvious (i.e. a word and not a number) then Excel is able to un-ambiguously convert it.

So `Jun 30 17` becomes `42916` (- which is 42,916 days since 31st Dec 1899).

Comment: This worked! Can you help me understand the logic behind it?

Comment: The date that you have is not a valid date for excel, is divided by a comma, and the year also has the `'` character. What he did was Split the date by the comma in the middle, he took the left portion of it `Fri Jun 30 '17`, removed the first 4 character, which is the day of the week and the space, also removed the `'` character from the year, and now he has `Jun 30 17`, a valid date for excel when using `DateValue`, he then used `Format()` to convert it to mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Added an breakdown explanation to my answer. If you're happy with it, please mark it as such.